# Same Table, Notification Hub and server for two apps

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-web-app-service

We got caught by Microsoft's abandonment of Silverlight and focus on UWP. This has ended up with us having to develop two dually focused apps (UWP and Silverlight), which has left us with two apps that cannot be bundled/packed together. We have therefore decided to have of the apps as a companion app.

Both apps use authentication, at present time it is with Microsoft authentication. The services used for authentication is of the type `Azure App Service - Mobile`. The services besides authentication also provides interfaces to a notification hub, blob storage and SQL storage.

The question is therefore is it possible to have one `App Service - Mobile` (not mobileservice), and authenticate two different apps using the same service?
Additionally can the same Notification Hub be used to send notifications towards different apps?

Or is it needed that we create two different services for each application to facilitate the use of authentication and push messages. Then we can link the same database to the two `App Service - Mobile` ? But this would leave the issue of the notification hubs not having the same registrations ?

Comment: What is Mobile App Service?

Comment: @juvchan Just made a small edit to that. It is an `App service` but it is a version of the `App service` like API or Web. But the mobile one is specifically in relation to having phone or computer apps runing with the service as support. Like the old MobileService.

Comment: That sounds clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by product group, the idea behind Mobile App is to be the individual backend. For that, Mobile Apps dashboard should have not one field for the PackageId/..., but two or more to be the backend for a different apps. Every connection between app and external service like a authentication provider or push notification platform is "personalized" - by IDs and password or certificates, or many ways.

I can imagine the scenario when someone would need to connect one backend to different apps, but the Azure Mobile App idea is different. And, as App Service is a service, i think that in the current situation what you want to do is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can have more than one apps connected to one Azure mobile app. You can connect same app on different platforms but not multiple applications for same platform as Mobile app is designed to be an individual app back end.
Check this feedback request.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/3821272-push-notifications-for-multiple-apps

Comment: That was what I feared. So the only thing I can do is create a new service in the same resourcegroup and then and connection string to the table data so they operate on the same data? Then I would also have individual authentication and notification hub.?

Comment: Yes they can connect to the same back-end database. authentication will go through your individual service. and notification hub will be separate too. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/7189494-multiple-cert-support-for-apns-in-azure-push-notif.

Answer (score 0):

an Azure Mobile App consists of the client app and a backend in Azure. There's no stopping you reusing the same backend for more than one app.

Comment: okay. Then want information should be inserted in the notification hub for client secret and SID ? the two apps have their own value for these. And what about authentication with  different client Id and client secret? Does these settings not matter if it is different apps communicating ?